# Keep main content scrollable but not the body

Tags: javascript, html, css

For a template such as:

[image: Scroll]

I'm using the following approach

- Get the height of the viewport via javascript (Let's say 500px)
- Deduct the header and footer height from it (Let's say header and footer are 50px each. So the end result will be 400px)
- Apply the end result as height of the main content div via javascript
- Use `overflow-y:scroll` property on the main content div via CSS

This works as expected but I was hoping there might be a better way to achieve the same. I'm thinking only via CSS, if possible.

The code I'm using is:

```
<!-- javascript -->
var height = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
var to_apply_height = height - 50 -50; // header and footer height
document.getElementById('main_content').style.height = to_apply_height+'px';

<!-- css -->
#main_content{
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). This works in all modern browsers, and will also make it responsive.

```
.wrapper {
  /* Makes the wrapper fill the entire screen */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* The important bit */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
  /* Makes the main content take up the remaining space */
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.header, .footer {
  height: 50px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekz8hLL8/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CSS3's [`calc()`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp) function with the [`vh`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) unit, like this:

```
#main_content{
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: What about browser compatibility? I don't suppose it's quite good.

Comment: @asprin I don't think it is possible with older browsers in a CSS only manner.